# Android Reflection - method not found

Tags: android, reflection

I am not able get method from below class. Does any one know how to do it?

In logs, I can see "pre-method found". But "Method found" never gets printed. Thats because 
Class.forName("android.content.pm.PackageParser.Package") throws noclassfound exception. I verified in Android source code multiple times that PackageParser.java is present and has Package class in it.

```
    Class _class = null;
    try {
        _class = Class.forName("com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService");
        Log.i("TEST", "Class found");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Method method = null;
    try {
        Log.i("TEST", "Pre-Method found");

        method = _class.getDeclaredMethod("grantPermissionsLPw",
                Class.forName("android.content.pm.PackageParser.Package"),
                Boolean.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Log.i("TEST", "Method found");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It may have something to do with your SDK version you're using.